# Why does changing the order of variable definitions change the functioning of code

Tags: c, dev-c++

There is two code written in Dev-c++ first one is working properly and another one is not, Why??

```
/* this code is working properly*/

#include<stdio.h>  
int main()
{  
    char op;    // this is the point 
    int a,b,c;  // where another code differs
    printf("Enter the two no.s:");
    scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
    printf("Enter the operation(+/-/*//):");
    scanf("%s",&op);
    switch(op)
    { 
     case '+': c=a+b;
               printf("%d",c);
               break;

     case '-': c=a-b;
               printf("%d",c);
               break;  

     case '*': c=a*b;
               printf("%d",c);
               break;  

     case '/': c=a/b;
               printf("%d",c);
               break;  

     default: printf("Invalid Operation");
     }
}
```

---

```
/* this code is not working properly; only altered the declaration sequence of int and char*/

#include<stdio.h> 
int main()
{  
     int a,b,c;   
     char op;
     printf("Enter the a:");
     scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
     printf("Enter the operation(+/-/*//):");
     scanf("%s",&op);
     switch(op)
     { 
     case '+' : c=a+b;
               printf("%d",c);
               break;

     case '-' : c=a-b;
               printf("%d",c);
               break;  

     case '*' : c=a*b;
               printf("%d",c);
               break;  

     case '/' : c=a/b;
               printf("%d",c);
               break;  

     default: printf("Invalid Operation");
     }
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s",&op);` -> `op` is a single `char`, yet you are trying to read in a string -> *undefined behavior*

Comment: Anyway - `scanf("%s",&op)` is UB, as `op` is `char`. Both snippets are broken.

Comment: replace %s-->%c

Comment: This is a nice example why this is called "Undefined Behavior" instead of error or crash or anything else. Environmental (and thus random) context influences how the program behaves. As you saw, this may range from "seems to behave correctly" (one extreme) to crash (the other extreme). In between is something even more terrible: "behaves most times correctly" (sporadic errors which usually apprear on customer side but never in your debugger). The reason was already pointed out twice: the wrong usage of `scanf()` which is unfortunately (usually) not detected by the C compiler.

Comment: `scanf("%s",&op);` -> `scanf(" %s",&op);`. Note the space before `%c`.

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%s",&op);` this will always cause a buffer overflow (undefined behavior) because %s always appends a NUL byte to the buffer. suggest using: `scanf("%c",&op);`   And always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful  I.E. `if( 1 != scanf("%c",&op) ) { handle error }`

Answer (score 4):

Here's your problem:

```
scanf("%s",&op);
```

The `%s` format specifier expects a pointer to *the first character of an array that can store a string*.  What you're passing in is the address of a *single character*.

As a result, when you enter a symbol such as `+`, this gets written to `op`, but then a null byte is written to whatever memory happens to be next after `op` to complete the string.  By writing to memory you're not supposed to, this invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

With undefined behavior, anything can happen.   You program may crash, it may show unexpected results, or it may appear to work properly.  Also, making a seemingly unrelated change such as adding a `printf` for debugging or (as in your case) changing the order of variables can change the way undefined behavior manifests itself.

To read a single character, you need to use the `%c` format specifier.  You'll also need to add a space to the format string before it to consume whitespace, namely the newline from the prior `scanf` call.  This is needed because `%c` does not skip whitespace by itself, unlike other format specifiers such as `%d` or `%s`.

```
scanf(" %c",&op);
```